# How can I constrain this filtering even more?

Tags: qgis, data, sql, filter, operator

I'm using QGIS and I am trying to filter a dataset using the advanced filter. My dataset contains earthquakes in the U.S., Canada and Mexico, however I would like to exclude Canada & Mexico for now.

The problem arises when I filter using:

```
  "place" LIKE '%Mexico%'
```

as this now includes Mexico AND **New Mexico**.

I've been trying to experiment with SQL commands but I've had no luck so far.

EDIT: Added screenshot of part of my attribute table, the column labeled "place" is what I'm trying to filter by. 
[image: Partial Attribute Table]

["earthquakes_2005.csv" dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mlzsb53x989z5a/earthquakes_2005.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Post a screen shot of your attribute table.

Comment: @whyzar posted it

Comment: Wildcards are *evil* -- Only use them when you ***know*** you can control the outcome. The proper SQL  syntax here is `WHERE "place" NOT IN ('Canada', 'Mexico')`

Comment: @Vince Did not work, could it be my QGIS version, 2.16? Also, the "place" column doesn't just contain one word locations like 'Mexico', instead it is like 'Baja California, Mexico' or 'B.C., Canada'.

Comment: @Vince Here's the error I got back: Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected COLUMN_REF, expecting $end

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Comment: Try %Mexico instead

Comment: How about **"place"  LIKE '%Mexico%' AND NOT "place" LIKE '%New Mexico%'**

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the values you have in ASCII, so that they're legible on all devices. I recommend adding a "country" column, then encoding it, so yhat indexing is possible. Wildcard and NOT searches are very inefficient  and *compound* search terms are even more so).

Comment: @Kazuhito Okay this works, however when I add Canada into the mix by using: "place" LIKE '%Mexico%' OR "place" LIKE '%Canada%' AND NOT "place" LIKE '%New Mexico%', now it includes New Mexico.

Comment: Could it be  "place" LIKE '%Mexico%' **AND NOT** "place" LIKE '%New Mexico%' **OR** "place" LIKE '%Canada%'  ?

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to **create a new field** (e.g. `new_place`) which can be used as a filter. This field will contain all the original place names but replaces "New Mexico" with another name (e.g. "New Méjico"). You can use an expression like:

```
regexp_replace( "place", 'New Mexico', 'New Méjico')
```

Now you can use an advanced filter on the new field to take out any rows containing "Canada" and "Mexico". "New Mexico" can still be seen in your original `place` field:

```
"new_place" not like ('%Canada') and "new_place" not like ('%Mexico')
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using

> "place" LIKE '%Mexico%'

add this additional constraint

> CHAR_LENGTH(“ColumnName“) > 6

to be

> "place" = 'Mexico' AND CHAR_LENGTH(“ColumnName“) = 6

[Here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm) are some additional query statements to keep in mind as well.

Comment: hmm getting this error: Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Comment: I've updated the syntax, also can you share the file if it doesn't execute?

Comment: Still didn't execute, I've uploaded the dataset

Comment: Isn't a simple `"place" = 'Mexico'` enough (i.e. without the wildcard `%`)? I don't think the `char_length` adds any more value.

Comment: Yea I suppose that works too